# Have NFL games been played at neutral venues before?

Tags: american-football, nfl, history

On week 13 of the 2020 NFL season, because of strict COVID-19 restrictions in their home county of Santa Clara, the San Fransisco 49ers played the Buffalo Bills at the State Farm Stadium in Arizona, home of the Cardinals, and will also play their next "home" game against the Washington Football Team there too.

Have there been previous occasions where a regular-season or post-season game (excluding the Super Bowl) has been played at a neutral venue because of particular circumstances that prevent the game being played at the home team's stadium?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The closest parallel in recent times is the Saints splitting their 2005 home games between LSU's Tiger Stadium and the Alamodome after Hurricane Katrina damaged the Superdome.

(They also played their first "home" game against the Giants in Giants Stadium, which probably doesn't count as a neutral venue)

Comment: There was also the Chargers playing a game in Arizona because of wildfires in 2003.

Comment: By coincidence, I stumbled across another such incident in 2010, where the [roof of the Vikings stadium collapses](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-11980078) under weight from the snow. The  subsequent game against the Giants was [moved to Detroit](https://www.espn.com/nfl/news/story?id=5911532)